# Second interview scheduling

Tags: interviewing, internship

I had my first interview and it went really well. How long should I wait before scheduling my second interview? Would 5 days out (including Saturday and sunday) look bad? I want to prepare a little bit and brush up on some topics before my second interview.

Comment: Have they contacted you to schedule the next interview? Usually the company will propose a timeline.

Comment: I'd say 3 business days, with followup every 2 days after.

Comment: @DavidK and Mike Yes they told me to select a date. They asked me today (Thursday) and I am probably going to put down next Wednesday, Thursday, Friday as my availability. From Thursday to next Wednesday is about 3 days not including weekends which I guess it's fine?

Comment: Is the interview taking place close to where you live or not?

Comment: Yes it is taking place at my school

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Three business days out is fine. It will not raise any eyebrows.**

Now I will answer your question more generally.

**You should schedule the second interview as early as you are comfortable setting it.**

Some benefits of scheduling the second interview earlier rather than later are:

1. It shows that you are confident and enthusiastic about the position.
2. It limits the window during which the interviewer(s) can choose to hire someone else, or during which a new candidate can apply.
3. If your first interview went well (it did; they asked you back) you will be fresher in the minds of the original interviewers, if they participate in the second round. Limiting the amount of time between the first and second interview limits the amount of time their favorable impression has to change. It may also feel more "natural" if you are fresh in the interviewer's minds.

The benefits of delaying the second interview will be, in most cases, less significant. If the second interview is a technical interview it may be tempting to give yourself multiple days to "study". But, unless it is an unusual technical interview in which you have something like a study guide, my experience is that most technical interview space is simply too broad to study for in the way you might study for a test in school.

Please do note that I suggest you schedule the second interview only as early **as you are comfortable** setting it. Your performance during the interview will weight **far** more heavily than any advantage you might gain or lose by choosing the interview date. The best thing you can do to maximize your performance is to be present and relaxed. This becomes very had to do if factors besides the interview are stressing you out. Interviews are stressful enough! Choose a date and time where you will not be rushing to the interview And make sure it is far enough out that you have emotionally recovered from the stress of the first round interview.

*But please don't take this advice to the extreme and try to schedule your round two interview, like, 15 minutes after being contacted. That might be perceived as weird :)*

Comment: These are some good points to keep in mind. Yeah I have a packed schedule on Monday and Tuesday since I am still in college so I had to pick Wednesday really had not choice. But I think 3 days out like you said should be fine just wanted to make sure since they gave me the option to select so I wasn't sure an acceptable time frame.